# j_security_check return error 405 (Request method 'POST' not supported)

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm have a simple login page. Right now it works without problems if you provide the right username and password. The problem is that, if you don't, you aren't redirected to the authenticationFailureUrl but you get an error 405.

**The only line of log:**

```
^2014-04-29 15:24:01,434       WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound    
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']    
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Any thought?

The application is running on Weblogic 11g

**URL:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:7013/app/j_security_check
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<sec:http create-session="stateless" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll()"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll()"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/account" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />

        [...]

        <sec:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"  />
    </sec:http>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>App</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:beanRefContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
        <param-value>beanRefFactory</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>net.xxxxx.xxx.xxx.webapp.XxxxxxApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginfailed</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <description>Power Users</description>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <resource-ref id="ResourceRef_1">
        <res-ref-name>STPDataSource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I may be paranoid, but can you try invoking the loginFailed URL directly from the browser? May be Spring tries to redirect to that URL and it goes to an unintended controller who's getting it? can you enable remote debugging and step through the Spring classes to track who's sending that 405?

Comment: I can access the loginFailed (/loginfailed) successfully.